# iPhone/iPad HTTP streaming library or server

Tags: iphone, http, ipad, streaming

Is there any available open-source (preferred) or commercial library for on-fly segmenting and streaming of video to iPhone / iPad?

Also, is there any open-source/commercial server (alternative to Wowza) which supports this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple offers mediastreamsegmenter:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html

You might also want to peek at Best Practices for Creating and Deploying HTTP Live Streaming Media for the iPhone and iPad:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2224/_index.html

There's also Darwin Streaming Server, but you may not need it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd appreciate if there any library (Java preferred) which can do in-memory segmentation and streaming.

Answer (score 2):

Your first preoccupation should be to try to peek a good segmenter (video speaking): Apple's one is fine.

Then, if you wan't in-memory segmenting, mount the input source folder to a RAMdisk...

Comment: Thanks, but question is if there a library that can perform this on fly?

Comment: @SyBer, this is 2 lines of code (assuming you are on a *nix environment, i have no idea how involved or otherwise it is

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at following link;
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html

This example will show how to play videos from a network based URL.

For [more details](http://developer.apple.com/search/index.php?Search=play+streaming+video) about playing videos;

Comment: Thanks, I have this link already, but looking for some kind of a library that can do it in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/)(java & opensource).

Check lastest beta, or code in svn (as lot hav changed since last officeial release).

It may or may not be able to do that out-of-the-box, if not you can code your red5 app and/or check others people code built arround red5...